# SOQL - group by getting 0 as key in result salesforce

Tags: soql

I want to group by result using two fields. I achieved that by writing following query

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) recordCount, 
       av_Date__c,
       Type__c 
FROM Unvailability__c 
WHERE av_Date__c = NEXT_N_DAYS:5
      AND Saved_by__c = '$intUserId' 
      AND Type__c != null
GROUP BY Type__c, av_Date__c
```

Result:

> Array ( [recordCount] => 2 [av_Date__c] => 2014-10-13 [0] => Personal
>   )

Expected Result:

> Array ( [recordCount] => 2 [av_Date__c] => 2014-10-13 [Type__c] =>
>   Personal )

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I've think you're executing this query via the API? Probably from PHP? Can you show us the surrounding code? Does it give the same result of you run the query in the Salesforce developer console?

Comment: Yes I am executing it through API. It gives expected result on Developer console

Comment: Can you share the surrounding code? Seems that something's not right on the PHP end.

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be due to either

- permission issue or
- sharing setting of Unvailability__c object

for the API user  you are using to execute the query.